# Unable to set -Dlog4j.configuration JVM parameter for JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I'm trying to decouple my log4j configuration file from a web application.

What I've done so far is convert my log4j.xml into a log4j.properties file, and add the following to my `pom.xml`

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
     <excludes>
        <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
     </excludes>
</resource>
```

Which creates `log4j.properties` file in the target directory, but does not include it in the generated `.war` file.

From here, I place the log4j.properties file in some location and attempt to reference it in my `standalone.conf` JBoss file, via the following JVM parameter:

`JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/some/path/to/log4j.properties`

However when doing this, no actual logging happens. I wouldn't think it would be necessary for me to need to do anything in the `standalone.xml`, but what I've done so far has not worked so I'm not sure. Is there an additional step I need to take to ensure I've properly set the `-Dlog4j.configuration` parameter and that JBoss is working with my `log4j.properties` file?

Comment: You're excluding it...

Comment: Have you excluded the logging subsystem or log4j in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?